# Run a function at every hours in cron

Tags: configuration, cron

I  want run a magento function that would run at every hour , i am written code in config.xml but i did not working.here the code in config.xml

```
<crontab>
            <jobs>
                <stockalert_autosend>
                <schedule><cron_expr>* */1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>stockalert/observer::backinstock</model></run>
            </stockalert_autosend>
            </jobs>
        </crontab>
```

I assume that there issue in  *** */1 * * *** Please help me

Comment: as of http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=*+*%2F1+*+*+*&iterations=10&test=Test your cronjob would run every minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this cron expression:

```
<cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

I'm not exactly sure what your expression does but I have a feeling it triggers every minute.

Answer (score 2):

If Magento actually supports that notation, you should use this:

```
0 * * * *
```

which will run the job on the hour every hour.

Using */1 is the same as *, so your original line runs the job every minute of every hour.